# how to joint four single byte data to four byte data entire

Tags: c

I want to combine four single bytes of data to one datum of four bytes.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    unsigned long int sdata = 0x12*(16^6) + 0x34*(16^4) + 0x56*(16^2) + 0x78;
    printf("%x %d", sdata, sizeof(sdata));
    return 0;
}
```

The screen prints:

```
c20 4
```

I want to get:

```
sdata = 0x12345678
```

The type `unsigned long int` is a 4 byte data type, so why can't it save the data? Why is the output wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unsigned long int` is not always 4 bytes, in many implementations it's 8 bytes.

As was said in the comments `^` does not represent power in C, it's a bitwise operator.

Your `printf` specifiers are not correct, you should use `%lx` in the first (or `%#lx` if you'd like to print the `0x` prefix) and `%zu` in the second.

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/rJPF33738)

Casting to `unsigned long` will avoid integer overflow, more so because there are some implementations in which `int` type is 2 bytes in size.

```
unsigned long int sdata = (unsigned long int)0x12*16*16*16*16*16*16 + (unsigned long int)0x34*16*16*16*16 + 0x56*(16*16) + 0x78;
printf("%#lx %zu", sdata, sizeof(sdata));
```

Output:

```
0x12345678 8 //in this demo, as you can see, unsinged long int is 8 bytes
```

Or just use binary operations if you can, as [demonstrated by @chmike](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62148242/6865932)

Answer (score 2):

You must use binary operations. More precisely left shifts (<<) and binary or (|).

```
unsigned int sdata = 0x12<<24 | 0x34<<16 | 0x56<<8  | 0x78;
printf("%x %zu\n", sdata, sizeof(sdata));
```

This yields

`12345678  4`